# from a dataframe column check if a string is nan

Tags: python, pandas

From a dataframe when I print `data['words'].values` I get,

```
['from' 'fairest' 'creatures' 'we' 'desire' 'increase' nan 'that' 'thereby']
```

When I loop through like this how do I identify if the value is nan?

```
for w in data['words'].values:
    check if w is nan ????
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the pandas method [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html) to test:

```
In [45]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'words':['from', 'fairest', 'creatures' ,'we' ,'desire', 'increase' ,nan ,'that' ,'thereby']})
df
Out[45]:
       words
0       from
1    fairest
2  creatures
3         we
4     desire
5   increase
6        NaN
7       that
8    thereby
In [46]:

pd.isnull(df['words'])
Out[46]:
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6     True
7    False
8    False
Name: words, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 2):

the question was about the if:

```
for i in range(150,160):
  if (pd.isnull(df['Text'][i])):
    print('is null')
```

or count all NaN:

```
cnt=0
for i in range(len(dframe)):
  if (pd.isnull(dframe['Description'][i])):
    cnt+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this is faster than @Max (last answer)
Imagine you have a list of titles which might be empty another method which I found is faster is:

```
nan_COLUMN_indexes=list(df.loc[pd.isna(df["COLUMN"]), :].index.values)
len(nan_COLUMN_indexes)
```

By doing this not only do you get the list of all indexes empty in the column but can then :

```
iterator=iter(nan_COLUMN_indexes)
next(itr,nan_COLUMN_indexes)
```

This allows you to fill and track CURRENT nan/null value or else pandas would return the First Occurence of the nulls/nan :D

or replace `pd.nan()` with `pd.isnull()` as per your requirement